# How to automatically print html pages

Tags: vb.net, printing

I have an application written in VB.Net - which is designed to automatically print html pages once a specific event was triggered...

However the printing itself gives me some headache.

I have dug into several approaches how to solve this, the simples approach I have found is this:

```
Dim proStart As New ProcessStartInf
proStart.FileName = RecordsToPrintDictionary.Item(element.Key).FolderStructureLink & "\print.html"
proStart.Verb = "print"
'proStart.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
Process.Start(proStart)
```

However this will open a print dialog, where I have to confirm the print job, before the data is sent to the printer.

I have two questions:

a) By using this approach, is it possible to supress the printing dialog, respectively make it always use the default printer?

b) If yes, is it possible to capture weather the print job was successful or not?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the [PrintQueueWatch](https://printqueuewatch.codeplex.com/) library to check wether the print was successful. I believe there's an event for it.